# Почему то не работает деление в программе. Язык C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#define TRUE 1
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    double S;
    unsigned K, i ;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Vvesty chislo K ";
        cin >> K;
        cout << "Vvedeno chislo K= " <<K <<endl;
        if (K > 0)break;
        cout << "Vvedeno nekorrektnoe chislo K! Vvedite drugoe chisslo" << endl;    
    }
    S=0.0;
    for (i=1; i<=K; i++)
    {
        S=S+1/i; \\часть где не работает деление, если 1/i
    }
    cout << "Summa riada ravna S= " << S << endl;
    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: При делении целого числа на целое число получается целое число. Исправьте `1` на `1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Деление целого на целое в С++ дает целое число, замените 1 на 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Результат автоматически приводится к целому числу (так как вы целое делите на целое) - следует явно привести его к дробному.
Необходимо привести переменную i к типу данных с плавающей точкой.